# Having problem with a nested controller spec with RSpec post rails 5

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

Given this contrived example:

```rb
RSpec.describe City::Road::HouseController, type: :controller do
  let(:house) { create :house }

  describe 'index' do    
    context 'a request is received without a valid basic-auth header' do
      it 'renders unauthorized' do
        before { method_that_unsets_basic_auth_header }
        get(:index, params: { house_id: house.id })

        expect(response).to have_http_status(:unauthorized)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

with the following routes:

```rb
namespace :city do
  namespace :road do
    resources :location, only: %i[show index] do
      resources :house, only: %i[index], on: :member
    end
  end
end
```

Why do I keep getting this error?:

```rb
 ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"city/road/house :house_id=>1}
```

I think it's because it's ignoring `location`.

I expect the route to be:

`/city/road/location/:location_id/house`

I've looked at the following questions/answers but none of them helped (though I admit I may have missed something):

1. [How to test controllers with nested routes using rspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962285/how-to-test-controllers-with-nested-routes-using-rspec)
2. [Rails Rspec controller testing with nested resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33678450/rails-rspec-controller-testing-with-nested-resources)
3. [RSpec controller for nested resources, before_action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37399068/rspec-controller-for-nested-resources-before-action)

Comment: What exactly do you expect the route to be?

Comment: AH, oops, thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 0):

I took another look at the other questions/answers I linked and I noted that they all had one difference then what I had.

I removed the `:member` option

```rb
namespace :city do
  namespace :road do
    resources :location, only: %i[show index] do
      resources :house, only: %i[index]
    end
  end
end
```

and the spec now passess green, I don't know why that would affect the spec epecily becuase the route looks the same with or without that option.

Comment: `member` indicates that you want the route in the ID scope of the parent scope. In this case that would be a `location_id`. So you can either do like you have done, or add a `location_id` parameter to your test.